# Docker container exits after few seconds

Tags: docker, hadoop

I'm executing the following command to mount [Hadoop-spark-pig-hive](https://hub.docker.com/r/suhothayan/hadoop-spark-pig-hive) docker container using port mapping,

```
docker run -p 8088:8088 -p 50070:50070 --name hadoop-spark-pig-hive -v C:\Users\Mr.Semicolon\Desktop\iit:/resource -d suhothayan/hadoop-spark-pig-hive:2.9.2
```

Just to confirm it is up and running I executed the command `docker ps`
[image]

And it works for a few seconds only and docker container exit without any message. Please can someone suggest why this is happening and how can I solve the issue?

**Note:** *I'm using Windows 10 Home environment and docker version 10.03.13 build 4484c46d9d*

As [Julien B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4346453/julien-b) requested I executed `docker logs` and got the following log message but still have no idea how to solve this,

```
/etc/bootstrap.sh: line 9: /usr/local/spark/conf/spark-env.sh: Permission denied

/

* Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server sshd

...done.

Waiting for hdfs to exit from safemode

Safe mode is OFF

Started
```

Comment: Docker containers stop when there is no running process. Most likely your process fails or reaches its end and as a result, the container stops. Try running `docker logs hadoop-spark-pig-hive` for more info.

Comment: @JulienB. Thanks for the advice and I added my log message into the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed a tutorial and Following command worked for me,

```
docker run -it -p 8088:8088 -p 50070:50070 --name hadoop-spark-pig-hive -v C:\Users\Mr.Semicolon\Desktop\iit:/resource -d suhothayan/hadoop-spark-pig-hive:2.9.2
```

According to [this](https://miykael.github.io/nipype_tutorial/notebooks/introduction_docker.html#:%7E:text=The%20%2Dit%20flag%20tells%20docker,to%20make%20available%20for%20docker.) notebook,

The `-it` flag tells docker that it should open an interactive container instance.